# PyLatex basic script won't run because script interpreter could not be found

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn PyLatex. I've installed it via pip and copied the basic code from [here](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/basic.html#the-code) and I'm getting this issue:

```
C:\Conner\Scripts>pylatAttempt.py
latexmk: The script interpreter could not be found.
latexmk: Data: scriptInterpreter="perl.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Conner\Scripts\pylatAttempt.py", line 23, in <module>doc.generate_pdf()
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line 193, in generate_pdf raise(e) 
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'latexmk', u'--pdf', u'--interaction=nonstopmode', u'basic.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I've downloaded MiKTeX 2.9, do I need anything else? What is going wrong here? From the docs it seems like all you need to install is pylatex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this it turns out that for PyLatex to work you also have to have Perl installed. Once I downloaded Perl from [here](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) it worked.
Make sure Perl is in the PATH.

Comment: Conner, I tried to edit my comment the same day but I could not! In fact it did work! I needed to do some configuration but as you suggested, Perl was needed

Answer (score 12):

You can change the compiler to pdflatex instead of latexmk which will work if you have installed miktex and pdflatex . latexmk is compiler by default.

```
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False,compiler='pdfLaTeX')
```

Comment: **Thanks**, it worked but the thing is that I am also able to create PDF using `latexmk --pdf` command so default should also work.

Answer (score 5):

I am using **Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.** and I faced the same issue when I first tried to execute the **PyLaTeX's example** available at
https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/latest/examples/basic.html.

1)  When I executed the copied code before installation of **MikTeX**

```
  (pylatex) G:\RishikeshAgrawani\ProjectsWin7\Python3\PyLaTeX\pylatex\01_basic>python 01
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "01_basic.py", line 24, in <module>
      doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
    File "C:\Anaconda2.5.0.1\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line 317, in genera
      u'or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.'
  pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found
  Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.
```

2)  After installation of **MikTeX**

You can see above output, it is looking for `LaTex compiler` that we can install by installing **MikTeX**.

Also  read [Using latexmk with MikTeX](https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex/wiki/Using-latexmk-with-MiKTeX).

You can download **MikTeX** at https://miktex.org/download.

```
  (C:\Anaconda2.5.0.1) G:\RishikeshAgrawani\ProjectsWin7\Python3\PyLaTeX\pylatex\01_basic>python 01_basic.py
  latexmk: The script engine could not be found.
  latexmk: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "01_basic.py", line 24, in <module>
      doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
    File "C:\Anaconda2.5.0.1\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line 269, in generate_pdf
      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    File "C:\Anaconda2.5.0.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'latexmk', u'--pdf', u'--interaction=nonstopmode', u'basic.tex']' returned non-zero exit
   status 1
```

3)  After installation of **STARWBERRY PERL**

You can see above ouptput, it is looking for `perl.exe`.

So I downloaded Strawberry perl from http://strawberryperl.com/ and installed it.

Now I successfully ran the code and got the PDF.

```
  (C:\Anaconda2.5.0.1) G:\RishikeshAgrawani\ProjectsWin7\Python3\PyLaTeX\pylatex\01_basic>python 01_basic.py

  (C:\Anaconda2.5.0.1) G:\RishikeshAgrawani\ProjectsWin7\Python3\PyLaTeX\pylatex\01_basic>
```

That's it.

Comment: +1. In case anyone stumbles onto this solution, this indeed work for me! However, I needed to restart my machine after the perl instalation, otherwise it would not work. Also, make sure perl is in your path (the instalation did this automatically for me, but who knows).

Comment: Thank you very much for the updates [ihavenoidea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585576/ihavenoidea).